# comparing two variables in c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, until-loop

learning c++ and I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious but I'm not sure why I dont get a message that  *i == j* even though after the 3rd iteration the numbers are the same ?

This is the output:

*8 is not equal to 12*

*9 is not equal to 11*

appreciate any hints!

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){

   int i=8;
   int j=12; 

   for (i,j; i!=j; ++i, --j)
   {    
   if (i == j) 
        {     
         std::cout << "i = j" << "\n";   // this part doesnt work
         break;
        }
   else 

        std::cout << i <<" is not equal to " << j <<"\n"; 

   }
}
```

Comment: perfect!  thank you @dynamic-squid , Vlad from Moscow and LinuX Man

Answer (score 2):

The loop is executed only when `i` is not equal to `j` due to the condition

```
for (i,j; i!=j; ++i, --j)
          ^^^^
```

When `i` is equal to `j` the body of the loop does not get the control because the condition evaluates to `false`.

You should change the condition in the loop. Also the `break` statement is redundant.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 8, j = 12;  not ( j < i ); ++i, --j )
    {    
        if ( i == j ) 
        {     
            std::cout << "i = j" << "\n";
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << i <<" is not equal to " << j <<"\n"; 
        }
    }       
}
```

Its output is

```
8 is not equal to 12
9 is not equal to 11
i = j
```

Pay attention to that in any case in general you may not use the condition `i != j` in the loop because when this range contains an even number of values when you can get an infinite loop. For example consider the case when `i` is equal to `10` and `j` is equal to `11`. In this case after the first iteration of the loop `i` will be equal to `11` and `j` will be equal to `10` and again `i != j`.:)

Answer (score 1):

You could have used for `(; i <= j; ++i, --j)`.

The following is modified version of your code, just changed from `!=` to `<=`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int i = 8;
    int j = 12;

    for (; i <= j; ++i, --j)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            std::cout << "i = j" << std::endl;
        }
        else
            std::cout << i << " is not equal to " << j << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8 is not equal to 12
9 is not equal to 11
i = j
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your loops stops when `i` is equal to `j`, before ever printing it out. And since you break out of your loop when `i` is supposed equal to `j`, you can rewrite it like this:

```cpp
    for (int i = 8, j = 12; i != j; ++i, --j)
        std::cout << i << " is not equal to " << j << "\n";

    std::cout << "i = j\n";
```